# Why I can find a vector normal to the plane using it's arguments

Tags: analytic-geometry

I know I can find a vector normal to the plane **a**x + **b**y +**c**z = 0 which is (**a**,**b**,**c**) but I don't know why.

I would be pleased if you could explain the method used to find vectors normal to the plane.

Thank You!

Comment: Because your equation says the dot product of $(a,b,c)$ with $(x,  y, z)$ is zero. Hence the former vector is perpendicular to the latter vector.

Comment: But if it wasn't zero?

Comment: then it would not be normal

Comment: But I mean, why do I find the vector normal to the plane in the way I find, do you get it?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the method used to find the vector normal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you know  $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is a point on the plane, and $\left<a,b,c\right>$ is a vector normal to the plane.  Then if $(x,y,z)$ is any other point on the plane, then the two vectors $\left<a,b,c\right>$ and $\left<x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0\right>$ are perpendicular -- this is precisely what "normal vector" means.  That, in turn, is equivalent to
$$\left<a,b,c\right> \cdot \left<x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0\right> = 0$$
which is the same as
$$a(x-x_0) + b(y-y_0) + c(z-z_0) = 0$$

This can be rearranged in the form
$$ax + by + cz = d$$
where $d$ is a constant that can be expressed in terms of the other parameters ($a,b,c,x_0,y_0,z_0$).

Now this whole procedure can be run in reverse:  if you are given an equation of the form
$$ax+by+cz=d$$
then if you find any point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ that satisfies the equation, you would have
$$a(x-x_0) + b(y-y_0) + c(z-z_0) = 0$$
which means that if $(x,y,z)$ is any other point satisfying the condition above, then the two vectors $\left<a,b,c\right>$ and $\left<x-x_0,y-y_0,z-z_0\right>$ are perpendicular to each other, which means that $\left<a,b,c\right>$ is a normal vector.

Answer (score 0):

The user @symplectomorphic tell you why. Your equation is one which passes through the origin, so we may take $p = (0,0,0)$ to be a point on our plane. If $(a',b',c')$ is a normal vector to your plane then $(a',b',c') \cdot ((x,y,z) - p) = 0$. And now you see that after simplifying, it is the coefficients of the remaining variables $x,y,z$ which automatically give the coordinates of the normal vector.

Comment: Why ((x,y,z) - p)?

Comment: Oh, remember by definition, this is the vector extending from $p$ to the point $(x,y,z)$. This is a clever way of denoting vectors in the tangent plane you wish to construct. Is that ok?

Comment: I'm starting to think this subject is way easier than it felt, Thank you!!!

Comment: Be careful. This subject is being masked under a bigger umbrella. If you keep going on and learn subjects like differential geometry, or riemannian geometry, you'll see everything here was massaged in a way that makes it presentable to beginning students like ourselves.